# cannot set cell spacing between cell in outlook - html emails

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

cannot achive a proper cell spacing in outlook and windows mail:

[image]

this is how should be:

[image]

this is the code i used:

```html
    <center>
    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" width="90%" style="border-spacing: 10px;border-collapse: separate; width:90%">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px">
        <table >
         <tr>
          <td >
           <a class="mcnButton " title="Leaderhip & Charisma" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-leadership-e-carisma?ed=112122" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Leadership e Carisma</a>
          
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
       <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px">
       <table >
         <tr>
          <td >
           <a class="mcnButton " title="Energia Focus e Resilienza" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-energia-focus-e-resilienza" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Energia Focus e Resilienza</a>
          
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px" >
        <table >
         <tr>
          <td >
           <a class="mcnButton " title="Leadership e Conflittualità" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-leadership-e-conflittualita" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Leadership e Conflittualità</a>
          
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
       <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px">
        <table >
         <tr>
          <td >
           <a class="mcnButton " title="Leaderhip femminile" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-leadership-femminile" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Leaderhip Femminile</a>
          
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </center>
```

I'm inside the mailchimp editor, how can I fix this? I tried `mso-cellspacing` but nothing, also I've read that margin is not supported in outlook,

thi set up works well in gmail

Comment: Have you tried a 3 x 3 table with CTA's? It would have worked and you dont need cell spacing to worry about. If you are interested let me know and I will post it as an answer with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setting is `cellspacing="0"` Try bumping it up to `cellspacing="10"`

By doing this, it works fine in Outlook 2016, 2013, 2010.

My tested sample code is below.

Good luck.

```
<center>
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" width="90%" style="border-spacing: 10px;border-collapse: separate; width:90%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px">
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <a class="mcnButton " title="Leaderhip & Charisma" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-leadership-e-carisma?ed=112122" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Leadership e Carisma</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px">
            <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <a class="mcnButton " title="Energia Focus e Resilienza" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-energia-focus-e-resilienza" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Energia Focus e Resilienza</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px" >
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <a class="mcnButton " title="Leadership e Conflittualità" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-leadership-e-conflittualita" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Leadership e Conflittualità</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="background:#D03C48;font-size:12px;padding:10px;border-radius:3px">
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <a class="mcnButton " title="Leaderhip femminile" href="http://www.cfmt.it/formazione/corso/yoga-coaching-leadership-femminile" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-decoration: none;color:#fff;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">Leaderhip Femminile</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: sorry i post another version of the code, i did try with set cellspacing to 10 but it didn't work, for now i solved setting a border

Comment: I just tried it with Outlook 2016 and it worked flawlessly. That's what my answer is based on. If you're going to change your code, you should have courtesy to update the code you're expecting us to help diagnose. To to otherwise wastes our time.